# Mongodb and PHP APC

Tags: php, mongodb, apc

I just ran a test creating 1000 non-persistent connections to mongodb via nginx/php fastcgi which took about 2.1 seconds on my dev machine. I then tried the same test using persistent connections, same result. I think I read somewhere that persistence in the php driver is now always enabled anyway. Next, I tried storing the connections to APC which resulted in a 7-9ms response time after the first request. Now I'm wondering a few things here:

1. There's almost never a time I can think of where I'd want to create more than one connection in my app at once and with a persistent connection from what I understand, new connections are created as needed by the mongo driver.
2. Creating a single connection seems to take about the same time as pulling the stored connection object from APC. Will caching the connection object ever really provide a benefit?
3. Caching the connection I know of course would still require some sort of check to see if it's even still a valid connection.. in performing this check each time, I wonder if it would negate the performance gain (if any) from pulling it from cache.

I can't seem to really find any material really covering any of this so I'm assuming it's because I'm confused in my understanding. Have any of you experimented with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as far as i know, APC is serializing data while storing it. so it would not make any sense to store any connection in APC.

Then, persistend connections will be reused by the php process for various requests. So a non persistend connection will be reestablished for each request the php process will receive.

Comment: Yeah that's about the conclusion I came to. The persistence is managed for you already but what I was curious if it'd give any performance benefits pulling the object from memory vs asking the driver if the connection exists and then rebuild the connection object.